# Sequelize push values

Tags: database, node.js, sequelize.js

How to make push values in Sequelize, analogical SQL-request `UPDATE table SET fields = fields + 'test'`?

Example:

```
table.find({where: {id: 1}}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.name); //returned 'abc'
})

//actions ( + 'test')

table.find({where: {id: 1}}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.name); //returned 'abctest'
})
```

(Sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table.find({where: {id: 1}}).then(function(result) {
    result.name = result.name + 'test';
    result.save();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have all parameters well formatted in the request body you can update any table value like this:

```
table.update( req.body,
            {where: { id: 1 } }
        )
        .then(() => {
            //some other stuff
        })
        .catch(app.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

with es6 you can wrote variables in a string writing all inside `:

```
table.find({where: {id: 1}}).then(function(result) {
    result.name = `${result.name}test`;
    result.save();
});
```

more information here:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings